# consuming a web service in Synfony 2

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, wsdl

I have a web service developed with webdev, and I want to consume it with Symfony 2.

At this time, I went for pure PHP. I tried to define objects as classes like they are described in the wsdl (which will allow me to create instances of the object directly).
Exemple :

```
class my_complex_type{

    public $my_basic_type1 = null ; 
    public $my_basic_type2 = null ; 
    public $my_basic_type3 = null ;

    public function __construct($my_basic_type1, $my_basic_type2, $my_basic_type3){
      $this->my_basic_type1 = $my_basic_type1 ;
      $this->my_basic_type1 = $my_basic_type1 ;
      $this->my_basic_type1 = $my_basic_type1 ;
    }

 // setters and getters ...
}
```

and call functions with :

```
public function my_function(my_type $parameters)
    {
      return $this->__soapCall('my_function', array($parameters));
    }
```

The problem I encounter with this method is that I think that this doesn't make the code as flexible as it should be and it's pretty annoying to re-code things that are already written in the wsdl.

So I wonder if you have any option that could be more handy (and maybe more Symfony-friendly)

editor's note: English isn't my native language so please don't blame me, I tried my best to make this topic intelligible

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you need to use a class more then once across your application you need to define it as a service. A service is a php object that performs some type of global task. One cool thing about services, are the fact that you can inject other services into them using a process called Injection.  I know you are worried about having your code flexible. I promise that this type of injection offers an extreme amount of flexibility. If you find that this is not flexible enough for you, then symfony has something called a factory which offers even more flexibility. Check it out....http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

Comment: Thanks, do you know if I am forced to create a Factory ?

Comment: If you want your class to be globally accessible across your whole application, and you don't think symfony's normal services offer enough flexibility, then yes, I would create a factory. Is There something in particular you are trying to accomplish that you think you can't with symfony's services?

Comment: ATM I just need to know how to proceed because the web service is not yet implemented (except 3 functions). So now, I think that I don't need a factory, but as the web service will grow, I think I will implement a factory. The purpose of my question is more like "Is creating a factory method optional ?"

Comment: Yup it is. You do not have to create a factory :)